# How to sum two columns in a third column in PowerApps table

Tags: powerapps

```
    Table({
        orderDate: "Lenovo Thinkpad",
        orderId: "Procurement",
        ordererValue: 10,
        customer: "499.99",
        customerEmail: orderValue * customer)
}
)
```

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29KHn.png)

How to sum two columns in a third column in PowerApps table?

Answer (score 1):

You can use formula in below format to get the sum of two columns in table and save in third column:

```
ForAll(
   YourDataSourceName As aPatch,
   Patch(
      YourDataSourceName,
      {orderId: aPatch.orderId},
      {ThirdColumn: aPatch.orderValue + aPatch.customer}
   )
)
```

**Reference**: [Sum of two columns in third column](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Sum-of-two-columns-in-third-column/td-p/1217874)

---

**Update**:

First of all, store your table data in one collection like:

```
ClearCollect(
    colTableData,
    Table(
        {
            orderDate: "Lenovo Thinkpad",
            orderId: "Procurement",
            ordererValue: 10,
            customer: "499.99",
            customerEmail: orderValue * customer
        }
    )
)
```

Then you can get sum like:

```
ForAll(
   colTableData As aPatch,
   Patch(
      colTableData,
      {orderId: aPatch.orderId},
      {customerEmail: aPatch.orderValue + aPatch.customer}
   )
)
```

Comment: How to fix that in my situation?

Comment: Which columns you want to "Add"? What is the name of third column where you want to save the resulting value? Are you using hardcoded table in app or data is coming from data source / collection? You can try to apply same logic for your data as given in above formula.

Comment: The sum column is the customerEmail, you can see in the code block.

Comment: Check updated answer. Can you try and let us know if it works for you?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to Ganesh's solution is to use the [AddColumns function](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-table-shaping), which returns a table with additional columns. If you have

```
Table({
    orderDate: "Lenovo Thinkpad",
    orderId: "Procurement",
    ordererValue: 10,
    customer: "499.99")
})
```

You can get the extra column with

```
AddColumns(
  Table({
    orderDate: "Lenovo Thinkpad",
    orderId: "Procurement",
    ordererValue: 10,
    customer: "499.99")
  }),
  "customerEmail", orderValue * customer)
```

You can also save the result of AddColumns in a collection to manipulate it later:

```
ClearCollect(
  allOrders,
  AddColumns(
    Table({
      orderDate: "Lenovo Thinkpad",
      orderId: "Procurement",
      ordererValue: 10,
      customer: "499.99")
    }),
    "customerEmail", orderValue * customer))
```